# Installing leiningen

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

I am trying to manually install Leiningen on OSX. Following the standard instructions at http://leiningen.org/, I:

1. Downloaded the script.
2. Copied it to ~/bin with my credentials. (I verified that bin is in my PATH)
3. Attempted to set it to executable:

   ~::bin user$ chmod a+x lein.sh
   (seems to work here)
     ~:bin user$
4. "Run it (lein) and it will download the self-install package"

Here is the terminal output:

```
-bash: lein: command not found
```

Why?

Comment if I can provide any relevant information.

Comment: This question would be better fit on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Agreed now that I re-read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the script is in the path and called `lein.sh` rename it to `lein`. and you should be good to go. Windows allows you to elide the extension of some file types but unix/linux does not.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is a good minor detail to understand. Just an extra note, you actually have to rename it with "get info" on lein.sh, renaming it while merely browsing it in the finder.

Comment: Morkrom, you may want to learn a little bit more about Unix shell commands.  I almost never do that sort of thing in the Finder.  It's quicker at a command prompt once you get used to it.  The Finder is convenient for some purposes, but there's nothing I do with the Finder that I couldn't do at a shell prompt.

Comment: @Mars, I admit my desire to have better command of the shell. Do you know any particularly useful resources or habits that have helped you attain this practical understanding?

Comment: Interesting question, @Morkrom.  I've been using Unix bash shell commands for decades, I guess.  I learned mainly from books, and I would have assumed that the books I learned from are no longer available.  But they're such great books, that some of them are still around! *Unix Shell Programming* and *Unix Power Tools* are two books that I learned from.  However, there are currently many books that look like they would be useful, and doing a web search for "unix shell scripting" or "bash shell scripting" brings up several tutorials that might be helpful.

Comment: @Morkom Way back in the day Unix in a Nutshell had a really nice shell reference. I'm sure there's a Linux in a Nutshell book that is similar and more relevant to today's world. A getting started guide on Bash would help too.